# several instances of bind serving same domain

Tags: linux, bind, forwarding

I am trying to configure two DNS-servers (bind) on 2 linux-servers (server1 and server 2) acting as master for the same domain. server1 is intended as primary server and can resolve a subset of all FQHNs of that domain and is supposed to forward all other queries (including those for 'its own domain') to server2.
Apparently this is not possible: If server1 detects a query as being part of the zone that it is configured as master for, it will not forward that query to another DNS, even if server1 cannot resolve that query. This is independent of what forwarding type is configured.
Is that correct, or am I missing something?

Many thanks,

Wolfgang

Answer (score 0):

What you seek is not possible (as you are performing it). In your current config, you would likely create loops. Causing your servers to (quickly) become swamped. Like a self inflicted DOS. :(

You can have several NS' for your domains/hosts. But only **one** master.

What you're *really* after to accomplish your intended task, is DNAME.

It's setup implementation has changed over the different versions of the BIND -- ISC NAMED.
So you'll want to review the administrators guide that comes with your version.

HTH

In answer to comment below:

OK this all depends on who fritz.box is delegated to.
So say server0 is master (primary) for fritz.box
Then on Server0

`linuxpc1.fritz.box (or just linuxpc1) IN DNAME Server1`

Likewise for linuxpc2.fritz.box

`linuxpc2.fritz.box (or just linuxpc2) IN DNAME Server2`

This all, of course means that Server0 has IP addresses for both Server1, && Server2

Hope this makes things clearer.

Comment: o.k. so I can stop trying ....
As far as I understand, DNAME allows the same IP to appear as part of two different domains. What I am trying to do is kind of the opposite: I want to distribute different FQHNs of the same domain on two different servers.

Comment: No. In fact it does almost *exactly* what you're after. It allows (sub) delegation of a domain. Meaning you can *forward* queries, for the *same* domain to your other NS. As I understood you were attempting.

Comment: Well, I would like to have linuxpc1.fritz.box to be handled by server1 and linuxpc2.fritz.box by server2.
As far as I understand DNAME (or even CNAME for that matter) would require all FQHNs to be handled by server 2 being assembled in a subdomain like linuxpc2.subdomain.fritz.box ?